# How to change a column name in HSQLDB when the existing name is a reserved word?

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I'm trying to upgrade our DB from HSQLDB 1.7 to the latest version.  Unfortunately someone has named a column "Default".  I can't seem to rename this column in SQL (this in 1.7 as the rename has to occur before the upgrade).

I have tried escaping the column:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN \"DEFAULT\" RENAME TO new_name");
```

and various variations (including '\" and []) and nothing seems to work, I always get back the following

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column not found: DEFAULT in statement [ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN "DEFAULT"]
```

I'm clearly missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately someone has named a column "Default"

The trouble seems to be the casing. Not only do double quotes "escape" your names, they also make them case-sensitive, unlike non-quoted names, which are case-insensitive in most databases. So you have to use the exact casing when renaming the column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN "Default" RENAME TO new_name
```

... or with JDBC:

```java
stmt.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN \"Default\" RENAME TO new_name");
```

Comment: I really hoped this was the answer, unfortunately it still doesn't work:  Column not found: Default in statement [ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN "Default"]

Comment: OK, nevermind, just discovered that the database upgrade method is being run twice, so the first time it works and the second time it obviously fails.  Thanks!

Comment: @JamesW: It happens to the best ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From the [HSQLDB guide](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html):

> All keywords, can be used for database objects if they are double
>   quoted.

So try to use this:

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name" ALTER COLUMN "DEFAULT" RENAME TO "new_name"
```

Comment: The column is already double quotes, it's just escaped with a \ because it is in a java string.  But adding double quotes around the table name actually seems to make things worse.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a **Backtick** (`).
This should escape the default string quite well.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ALTER COLUMN `DEFAULT` RENAME TO `new_name`
```

Comment: That's how you quote names in MySQL, not HSQLDB